# Parse CSV file but no formatting except delimiting the data

Tags: java, csv, univocity

I have data in the below format

```
PAL : PAL : NF : "INCOME"."Taxable"
PAL : PAL : NF : "EXPENSES"."TotalExpenses"
PAL : PAL : NF : "EXPENSES"."Exceptional"
```

In java, i just want to delimit the data without doing any formatting, in the outputs also quotes should come. I usually use Univocity, when using the below code,

```
    //Simple CSV File Read
    List<String[]> allRows;
    try {
        CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
        settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
        settings.getFormat().setDelimiter(':');

        CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
        allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(new File(csvFile)));
        int i =0, cols=0;
        for(String[] str:allRows){
            i++;
            cols = str.length;

            for(String s:str)
                System.out.print(s+" == ");

            System.out.println("");
            if(i == 10) break;
        }       
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output was like below, period symbol is within quotes, i am expecting output to be like input, quotes should come.

```
PAL == PAL == NF == INCOME"."Taxable
PAL == PAL == NF == EXPENSES"."TotalExpenses
PAL == PAL == NF == EXPENSES"."Exceptional
```

Expected Output

```
PAL == PAL == NF == "INCOME"."Taxable"
PAL == PAL == NF == "EXPENSES"."TotalExpenses"
PAL == PAL == NF == "EXPENSES"."Exceptional"
```

Comment: seems like a lot of work to read in a simply formatted file. why not use a buffered reader and do readLine().split(":") instead and youre done?

Comment: Works for me, except the output of each line has an extra `==` at the end. But both double quotes are there

Answer (score 1):

Author of the library here. The thing is that `"INCOME"."Taxable"` is being handled as a quoted value, and it is treating the quotes between `INCOME` and `Taxable` as unescaped quotes.

It will basically try to "rescue" the value and find either a closing quote or a delimiter (determined by `settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(...)`).

In your case the easiest thing to do is to set your quote character to something like `'` or even `\0` if your input doesn't have to handle quoted values anyway. With this you should get `"INCOME"."Taxable"` as you expect.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I originally thought of it as a bug but then decided it was really a feature where you made a reasonable guess on handling abnormal input. +1

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a combination of a bug in your code and a relaxation of the CSV spec in Univocity.

The input was

```
"INCOME"."Taxable"
```

Unfortunately, this is NOT valid CSV, as you have a string containing embedded quotes.  The correct CSV encoding would have been

```
"INCOME"".""Taxable"
```

The Univocity library seems to have been non-strict about this and guessed that the input was meant to be a single string (since there was no input delimiter) in there.  So, after parsing the internal value of that field was

```
INCOME"."Taxable
```

This is the actual contents of the string, without the outside quotes that are required to make it a string *literal* in Java.

Then when you wrote it out you neglected to add back the surrounding quotes, resulting in the output you see.

Summary:

1. Univocity handled invalid input in a way that matches your requirements, so you're OK there.
2. To fix your problem you have to put back the surrounding quotes yourself

   ```
   int field = 0;
   for(String s:str) {
       if (++field == 4)
           System.out.print("\"" + s + "\"");
       else
           System.out.print(s + " == ");
   }
   ```

This also fixes the other bug of the extra trailing `==` delimiter.

Comment: Thanks. Since my actual input has lot of fields, i was thinking Univocity could handle this.

Comment: By default the library tries to "rescue" from unescaped quotes. There are some options to handle thse situations, including `settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(RAISE_ERROR);`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do something like this and i tested the result as well. Please tweak your code accordingly.

Your data:

```
PAL : PAL : NF : "INCOME"."Taxable"
PAL : PAL : NF : "EXPENSES"."TotalExpenses"
PAL : PAL : NF : "EXPENSES"."Exceptional"
```

Code:

```
public static void parseFile(){
        String csvFile = "file/User.csv";
            String line;
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String equal_string = line.replaceAll(":", "==");
                    String quoate_string = equal_string.replaceAll("\"\"", "\"");

                    if(quoate_string.startsWith("\"") && quoate_string.endsWith("\"")){ 
                        String final_string = quoate_string.substring(1, quoate_string.length()-1);
                        System.out.println(" final : "+final_string);
                     }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
 final : PAL == PAL == NF == "INCOME"."Taxable"
 final : PAL == PAL == NF == "EXPENSES"."TotalExpenses"
 final : PAL == PAL == NF == "EXPENSES"."Exceptional"
```

Comment: :D. Thanks. I have coded something similar as well. Since my input has a lot of fields, i thought univocity could handle this.

Comment: That is awfully slow. If this is a concern using the library is the best way to go about it.